# How to add string if exist with other character

Tags: python, split

I have a string below

if input is `Test` then the output is `('*Test*')`

if input is `'Test,Test1'` then output is `('*Test*','*Test1*')`

if input is `'Test,Test1,Test2'` then output is `('*Test*','*Test1*','*Test2*')`

Input will be separated with any number of commas

- The input is string separated by `,`
- I need to insert * at every string at beginning and end

Comment: Is this homework? Have you made an attempt yet?

Comment: I also don't understand the last test case.

Comment: *+ input + * will give the output will give only the satisfy the first condtion

Comment: @msanford edited

Comment: @JanStránský  no it wont the input will be separated with any number of commas

Comment: @JanStránský nothing just put like that to readable

Comment: "*+ input + *", "nothing just put like that" - If you want a good answer, you should describe your problem in detail..

Comment: @JanStránský  can you check the question now. Please upwote also

Comment: @Maws The parenthesis and quotation marks make it really confusing. Please provide clearly input -> output. Put some code (even if it does not what you want) to see if in the case of `'Test,Test1'`, the quotation marks are part of the string or not etc. Unclear problem and no code (no shown effort) definitely is not suitable for upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the structure you can assume the string to have. It seems to be words separated by commas. If that is indeed always the case, I would do something like:

```
s = '(Test,Test1)'
output = '(' + ','.join([f'*{word}*' for word in s[1:-1].split(',')]) + ')'
```